# Mutate a grouped value (like a conditional mean)

Tags: r, dplyr

With **dplyr** and **R**, you can use *group_by* and *summarize* to aggregate data.

For instance:

```
mpg_cyl_carb <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, carb) %>% 
  summarise(var1 = mean(mpg))

head(mpg_cyl_carb, 3)
A tibble: 3 x 3
Groups:   cyl [2]
    cyl  carb  var1
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     1  27.6
2     4     2  25.9
3     6     1  19.8
```

It means that when cyl = 4 and carb = 4, the mean for mpg is 27.6.  When cyl = 6 and carb = 1, the mean is 19.8, and so on.

I would like to nest those aggregate results on the original dataframe. Currently am joining two tables to do this:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   left_join(mpg_cyl_carb, by = c("cyl", "carb")) %>% 
+   head(3) %>% 
+   select(mpg, cyl, carb, var1)
   mpg cyl carb  var1
1 21.0   6    4 19.75
2 21.0   6    4 19.75
3 22.8   4    1 27.58
```

But is there an easier way? A single command for mutate, like:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   mutate(. . .)
```

Not a solution using if_else, as it would add complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `group_by` before the `mutate` to create the `mean` column by group - instead of creating a `summarise`d dataset and then joining to original data

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl, carb) %>%
   mutate(var1 = mean(mpg)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   head
```

Comment: Generally, group_by is followed by a summarise command, but this is a good example where group_by + mutate go together well. Thank you!